# How to hide and show category name on the base of its post status in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, posts

I have categories then its sub categories and posts in those, now on the base of post status (that either it is public or private) I want to hide and show the main categories of that post.

I want when a sub category have all posts as private then the main categories(of those private posts) should not show to logged off user.

Comment: Here people understand code better that English :) So can you show your code ?

Answer (score 0):

You could set a variable to keep track of the posts that are public.

Do a query where you are searching for posts that are public. You can do something like `if(mysqli_num_rows($queryResult) > 0) { $hasPublicPosts = true; }` and then based on that variable you can decide whether to show that specific category or not.

The problem with doing this however, is that speed in which your page loads will slow down.

Pros: It works.

Cons: The larger your category gets the more time it takes to parse through all posts in a category.